# Anroid i try change my butten background colour by drawable xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button, android-theme

i tried to design butten by drawable xml file corner are working properly but color is not working properly

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/but_draw"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="purple">#564999</color>
    <color name="blue">#59b7e0</color>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer.**
Use something like:

```
   <Button
      app:backgroundTint="@null"
      android:background="@drawable/but_draw"
      ../>
```

or **better**:

```
    <Button
        app:cornerRadius="15dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        ../>
```

[image]

**Long answer.**.
The `Button` is replaced by a `MaterialButton` because you are using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme and the custom background is tinted with the `?attr/colorPrimary` defined in your theme.

In your case you are using a custom background only to define rounded corners. This feature is provided **by default** by the `MaterialButton`, then just use the **`cornerRadius`** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**replace this** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

**with this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use backgroundTint. background attribute as far as know is a kind of
deprecated